Autofac delegate factory with optional parameters
I am trying to create a delegate factory in autofac that allows for some parameters to be avoided. My idea is to register a class with registration parameters and be able to override it in the delegate factory if necessary.
Here is the code I have so far:
using Autofac;

namespace TestProject4;

[TestClass]
public class TestAutofacDelegateFactoryConParámetroNulo
{
    public class ClassThatHasDelegateFactory
    {
        private readonly TimeSpan _timeout;

        public delegate ClassThatHasDelegateFactory Factory(TimeSpan? timeout);

        public ClassThatHasDelegateFactory(TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            _timeout = timeout;
        }

        public TimeSpan Timeout => _timeout;
    }

    public class ClassThatUsesDelegateFactory
    {
        ClassThatHasDelegateFactory.Factory class2Factory;

        public ClassThatUsesDelegateFactory(ClassThatHasDelegateFactory.Factory class2Factory)
        {
            this.class2Factory = class2Factory;
        }

        public TimeSpan ClassThatHasDelegateFactoryTimeout() => class2Factory(null).Timeout;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void EsPosibleUtilizarDelegateFactoryConParámetroNulo()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ClassThatHasDelegateFactory>()
            .WithParameter("timeout", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
            .ConfigurePipeline(p =>
                {
                    p.Use(Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.PipelinePhase.ParameterSelection, (context, next) =>
                        {
                            context.Parameters.First();                            
                            next(context);
                        });

                })
            .AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<ClassThatUsesDelegateFactory>().AsSelf();
        //builder.Register((c, p) => new ChromeDriver()).As<IWebDriver>();
        var container = builder.Build();

        using var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
        Assert.AreEqual(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), scope.Resolve<ClassThatUsesDelegateFactory>().ClassThatHasDelegateFactoryTimeout());
    }
}

I was thinking I could maybe achieve it using ConfigurePipeline() but as of now I am stuck and I am not even sure it is the most straight-forward way of achieving it.
